# Why doesn't Mathematica ComplexExpand integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, complex

Consider this code example:

```
ComplexExpand[Re[Integrate[f[t], {t, a, b}]]]
```

Mathematica gives me the result as

```
Re[Integrate[f[t], {t, a, b}]]
```

which is obviously not helpful and not what should happen in my understanding. If all variables are real - and that's what `ComplexExpand` assumes according to the documentation - then `Re` can be dropped from the expression. The same happens for `Im`. This seems to confuse `FullSimplify` which leaves me with a long expression that could be shorted. Why is this the case? How can I get `Integrate` (and `Re`) to evaluate properly to simply

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, a, b}]
```

Comment: It works on inactive integrals in V12.1.1.

Comment: Let me rephrase: It does what you wanted done.

Comment: Whenever you alter an expression, it reevaluates (unless held). Evaluating `Integrate` is often very expensive; depending on the version, IIRC, some parts cannot be interrupted. Blithely letting `Simplify` etc. hack away at it might be the last thing the kernel would ever do: You'd have to kill (force-quit) it and restart the kernel. If it were my system, I think I'd protect the user from that and maybe invent `Inactive` -- actually, I was using `Hold` for years to do that before they introduced `Inactive`. That said, the algebra of inactive integrals (and sums) is not fully realized.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think I understand what you mean. But how can I resolve this?

Comment: My comment was my limited user-view response to your question, "Why is this the case?"  But perhaps your real question is how to get ComplexExpand to work on `Integrate` or implement such a function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right. I updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: The fact that `t` is real (for real `a` and real `b`) does not necessitate that `f[t]` is real for an arbitrary `f`.